# Passing "A string representation of an embedded instance"

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, hyper-v

[Msvm_ReplicationService::GetReplicationStatisticsEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280530(v=vs.85).aspx) method requires two parameters:

```
[in]  CIM_ComputerSystem ComputerSystem,
[in]  string ReplicationRelationship,
```

ReplicationRelationship is an object so I have no idea why it requires it as a string. 
The documentation says:

"ReplicationRelationship [in] A string representation of an embedded instance of the Msvm_ReplicationRelationship class that defines the replication relationship for which to retrieve the replication statistics." No idea what that means!

I am getting an "Invalid Parameter" error when I pass in the following:

```
rel.ToString()
```

and

```
rel["InstanceID"].ToString()
```

Anybody know how to actually call this method?

This is where rel comes from:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\virtualization\\v2", "SELECT * FROM Msvm_ReplicationRelationship"); 

    foreach (ManagementObject rel in searcher.Get()) {
        //string representation of rel required here
        //At the moment, just looping through all relationships for simplicity
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [getText()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementbaseobject.gettext(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) method? I think this returns the representation needed.